# Stop Screen Reader to read my control type in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, narrator

I have an old WPF application with needs and accessibility features. The application uses radio buttons to construct a menu with a popup.

The problem is the user doesn't want the narrator to say "radio button" when it's clicked. I am using `AutomationProperties.HelpText` and `AutomationProperties.Name` to adjust the text for the controls. I have no idea how to change the "ControlType" the narrator reads out when the control is in focus.

```
        <RadioButton
            AutomationProperties.AcceleratorKey="1"
            AutomationProperties.AccessKey="3"
            AutomationProperties.AutomationId="2"
            AutomationProperties.HelpText="Taufiq"
            AutomationProperties.ItemStatus="Test"
            AutomationProperties.ItemType="Text"
            AutomationProperties.Name="Take Snapshot"
            Command="{Binding TakeSnapshotCommand}">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <ContentControl Content="{DynamicResource GalleryIcon}" Focusable="False" />
                <TextBlock Text="Take Snapshot" />
            </StackPanel>
        </RadioButton>
```

None of the properties of the AutomationProperties works.

Comment: perhaps the narrator is using reflection to read the type and therefore gives out "radio button". perhaps extend the narrator or read up on how to supply a different title to the narrator

Answer (score 1):

My understanding is that narrator will read the advertised type so that someone relying on the screen reader knows how to interact with the focussed item.

If you really need to control how this works, you'll need to subclass `RadioButton` and override `OnCreateAutomationPeer` to create your own peer which can then gain quite a bit of control.